# Garbage code showing up in search result post descriptions

Tags: description

I don't know why this is showing up on all my post descriptions in Google:

```
        _// _ // ]]> //
```

It is driving me crazy. I am new to this but feel this is the reason my posts are not posting alone in Google. They are only tied to my home page in Google.

Comment: How are you getting `the_content()` and what filters, if any, are applied to it?

Comment: when I search for my posts in google that is showing up before every description. Im really new to this and no other site in google has this in front of their description.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a deductive logic approach and: 1) change themes and 2) deactivate plugins to find what it is putting that garbage code in, and 3) view page source to see under what theme/plugin combinations it is in page source.

First thing to do is view page source and see where that garbage code is appearing. Don't know how to view page source? See http://www.wikihow.com/View-Source-Code

Then change to the default WordPress theme, view page source, see if that same garbage code is there. If it is, replace all core WP files and folders (but not wp-content or wp-config.php). If it's not, than the theme you are using is the problem.

Deactivate all plugins, too, and see if the code is in page source. Reactivate one at a time until you see the code again. SEO plugins will generate the page descriptions.